Extending linear isometry from subspace to whole space
Problem: Let $(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V)$ and $(W, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_W)$ be finite-dimensional inner-product spaces, such that $\dim V\leq \dim W$, and let $U\subset V$ be a subspace. Show that every isometry $s\colon U\to W$ can be extended to an isometry $S\colon V\to W$, for which $S|_U=s$.
So far: Since $U$ is a subspace, we can find an orthonormal basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ for it. Now $(v_1, \ldots, v_k)$ is linearly independent in $V$, so it can be extended to a basis of $V$, and applying Gram-Schmidt to this basis we get an orthonormal basis $(v_1, \ldots, v_k, w_1, \ldots, w_\ell)$ of $V$, where $k+\ell =\dim V$. Now, if this were just a linear map and not an isometry, we could just choose $S(v_j)=s(v_j)$ and $S(w_i)=0$ and be done.
But now nothing guarantees this extended linear map is an isometry, and I haven't used the assumption $\dim V\leq \dim W$ at all. Since $s$ is an isometry, we know $(s(v_1), \ldots, s(v_k))$ is orthonormal in $W$ - should I extend this to an orthonormal basis of $W$ and leverage that somehow?

Yes, extend $(s(v_1), \dots, s(v_k))$ to a basis of $W$ and send the $w_j$ to the additional members of the orthonormal basis of $W$.

Got it, and if say $\dim U=1, \dim V=2$ and $\dim W=3$, does it matter to which basis vector of $W$ I send the (in this case) second vector of the basis of $V$?

The answer is no, right? And hence $S$ is not necessarily unique.

No, it is not unique at all (by the very argument you gave).

You can also see that it does not need to be unique be considering the case $U={0}, V=W$, then any isometry from $V$ to itself will do the job.
